200A panel upgrade, ready for inspection?
I just completed my service and panel upgrade to 200A, including installation of an emergency disconnect and an EVSE. The old service was 100A, fortunately the meter pan and utility wiring was ready for 200A. I received my cut-in card a while ago when I had completed the line-side of the emergency disconnect. I have a final inspection scheduled for Monday, and I'm curious if you see any issues with this install. Anything I should fix before the final inspection?
Here are some of the details that might be hard to see in the pictures:

#4 copper THHN from where the water pipe enters the building to the exterior disconnect
#4 copper from the two ground rods to the exterior disconnect (could have been #6 but I had #4 left over)
#4 copper bonding jumper between hot and cold water pipes at the water heater.
2/0 copper from exterior disconnect to panel inside the garage
#2-2-2-4 aluminum SER from garage (sub) panel to kitchen (sub) panel, protected by a 90A breaker in the garage panel. The kitchen panel has a 100A main breaker.
Main bonding jumper installed in exterior emergency disconnect, no bonding in sub panels
There is a ground bar in the 12x12x6 junction box above the panel. The grounds for all the circuits coming through the JC are terminated in that JB. There are three nipples connecting the JB to the panel, each nipple has a #8 or #4 copper ground jumper to the ground bar in the panel below. The ground bar has three 8-32 screws into tapped holes in the JB, I also scraped the paint behind the ground bar.
The junction box is very messy because it also contains the CT's for my Emporia Vue gen 3 energy monitor.
The 48A EVSE is spliced with Polaris connectors in the JB with #6 copper THHN, and protected by a 60A breaker. (I don't really need 2 EVSE's, but I needed a smart one for a rebate program and kept the old 30A Clipper Creek installed for now)
The 14-50 outlet is wired with #6 copper THHN with a #8 THHN ground. I used a lay-in lug to connect the ECG to the box.
I used a large torque wrench for all the major lugs and a small torque wrench for the breakers and Polaris connectors.
I installed a Siemens FirstSurge surge protector in the bay next to the panel. I put a 3/4" rigid conduit coupler (1 1/2" long) through a 1 1/4" hole in the stud and put a chase nipple on the panel side and an ENT connector on the surge protector side. This allowed me to keep the wires for the surge protector as short as possible and land them near the main breaker. I covered it with a plumbing access panel, and plan to drill holes in the cover to show the LEDs. Any issue with using ENT here?
The Tesla PowerWall+ used to be connected through a line-side tap. I moved it to a 50A breaker on the opposite side of the bus from the main breaker. The bus bars in this Leviton panel are rated for 225A

The old panel and sub-panel setup:

The new panel, junction box, EVSE and 14-50 outlet:

New setup without covers:

Junction box above panel:

Surge protector:

Drywall cover for surge protector:

Connections from surge protector to breaker (labeled "S")

Ground lug for 14-50 receptacle

Overview outside showing new Emergency Disconnect

Disconnect wiring:

Neutral and ground connections:

Kitchen panel:


@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact no specific use at this time. Could use it for a welder, RV (for visitors), or an plug-style EVSE. Wanted to get it installed now because my permit is still under the 2017 code and I prefer not to have to put a GFCI breaker for 240V 50A. Do I have to account for it in my load calc?

The GFCI reason is a good one. Not sure how to account for that in load calc.

The 14-50 with all the other stuff is starting to take a pretty big bite out of your Load Calc.  EV charging does not get the demand factor derate (40% fold-down) like other loads in NEC 220.82.  So a 48A station takes a full 48A bite out of the load calc, or 60A if the AHJ sees it that way, which they have good reason to do. And then ditto again for the Clippercreek.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica good to know EV charging doesn’t get 40% reduction. Does just the fact of having a 14-50 require you to assume the full 50 A in the load calc? What if it is intended for a welder?

@ChristianK Other appliances that are not EV or HVAC generally enjoy the 40% treatment. Heaters get a 65% treatment.  NEC is still unclear on the treatment of EV charging, but AHJs are treating it as 100-125% because it's such a brutal load. * (or rather, charging at high power is a brutal load. A 12,000 mile/year EV getting 3 mi/kWH only needs 4000 kWH/year or 11 kWH/day or 450 watts on average, or 1350W 8 hours a day.)

I passed inspection. The inspector only asked what gauge wire I used for the EVSE (#6) and how the ground bar in the Leviton panel was bonded to the case. He was satisfied when we found one screw that goes from the ground bar into the enclosure. I was a bit surprised about his question since it comes that way from the factory.
